# how to solve java7 nio socket WritePendingException?

Tags: java, scala, sockets

java doc said it will occurred when do write operate by former wirte not complete.

> Unchecked exception thrown when an attempt is made to write to an
>   asynchronous socket channel and a previous write has not completed.

a simple code to describe this stage:

```
  sendMsg(data: ByteBuffer): Future[Unit] = {
    val p = Promise[Unit]
    this.synchronized {
      //socketChannel: AsynchronousSocketChannel is connected socket
      socketChannel.write(data, 1, new CompletionHandler[Integer, Int] {
        override def completed(result: Integer, attachment: Int): Unit = {
          p.trySuccess(Unit)
        }

        override def failed(exc: Throwable, attachment: Int): Unit = {
          p.tryFailure(exc)
        }
      }
    }
    p.future
  }
```

I attempt to lock `write` operation until it completed with this unwork code:

```
val writeLock = new ReentrantLock

def sendMsg(data: ByteBuffer) = {
  val p = Promise[Unit]

  writeLock.lock()

  socketChannel.write(data, 1, new CompletionHandler[Integer, Int] {
    override def completed(result: Integer, attachment: Int): Unit = {
      writeLock.unlock()

      p.trySuccess(Unit)
    }

    override def failed(exc: Throwable, attachment: Int): Unit = {
      p.tryFailure(exc)
      writeLock.unlock()
    }
  })
  p.future
}
```

but it throw `IllegalMonitorStateException` exception.
Hope some help to to run it concurrently.
Besides, I have another question, why not java sdk deal with it.It seems I should wait a async operation complete.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is not that Java should handle this, because if it would you would be loosing control over your code.

You don't have to "wait". You write your data, and "invalidate" the client for writing. When the write is completed (that's why you have such method), you re-validate the client for writting.

The key concept is that, when selecting channels to write, you skip those that are "invalid" at that momment.

I made a nio async io implementation few years ago, you might take a look to get further hints

https://github.com/NadirRoGue/asyncnetworkengine/tree/master/src/org/mmocore/network

Take a look specifically at
`MMOClient.sendPacket()`
`WriteHandler.completed()`

Comment: In `MMOConnection.startWriteTask` where you use the `write` method in the thread pool.But the method invoked at `MMOConnection.executeWriteTask` which just lock current thread surround the `startWriteTask` method. how to ensure `executeWriteTask` can't execute when `write` is pending?

Comment: @LoranceChen that's why I have the `_pendingWrite` flag, to avoid executing it while pending. Another approache would be to use the `completed` method to trigger next write while the `sendQueue` has packets. Once this one is empty, the write task will stop being triggered, so you will have to use `sendPacket` (with another flag, which in the end is the same) to trigger the write task

Comment: ,could you give me a example to use the lib? I think the `_pendingWrite` is not affect at all because `_core.executeWriteTask` will return immediately.